# Finding the top 3 subset values of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with around 1000 values, which are in date order.

I want to find the three largest subsets of that data. Highest and Lowest are easy of course. I wrote this quickly so I know it's not the best.

It was done just to try it on a small sample of data. The example is in PHP.

```
<?php
$values=array(array (1,1),
array (2,2),array (3,553),array (4,455),array (5,655),array (6,774),
array (7,878),array (8,2359),array (9,0),array (10,56),array (11,756),
array (12,1234),array (13,6),array (14,4),array (15,23),array 
(16,763),array (17,235),array (18,72),array (19,465),array (20,7));
$highest=-1;
$runningtotal=0;
$lowest=1000000000000000;
for ($i=0;$i<18;$i++){
    $runningtotal=$values[$i][1]+$values[$i+1][1]+$values[$i+2][1];
    if ($highest<$runningtotal){$highest=$runningtotal;}
    if ($lowest>$runningtotal){$lowest=$runningtotal;}
}
echo $highest."<br>".$lowest;
?>
```

How can I find the top 3 subset values of it?

Comment: 1. *in date order* What does that mean? That you have an array full with dates or what? 2. But if I look at your code it looks like you want to find the 3 biggest arrays with the highest sum in `$values` ?!?

Comment: If you want to find the best subset of your main array made of 3 consecutive arrays, then your code seems right. What's the problem exactly ?

Comment: Multi-dimensional array date is first part of array and second is the value for that date. The example was simplified just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Rizier: Yes that is correct the Values array. Dates and Values are stored in $values and then I want to have the highest total for 3 consecutive array elements. Showing the highest, next highest and so on. I've added what I think is the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$values=array(
array (1,1),
array (2,2),
array (3,553),
array (4,455),
array (5,655),
array (6,774),
array (7,878),
array (8,2359),
array (9,0),
array (10,56),
array (11,756),
array (12,1234),
array (13,6),
array (14,4),
array (15,23),
array (16,763),
array (17,235),
array (18,72),
array (19,465),
array (20,7)
);
$highest=-1;
$runningtotal=0;
$lowest=1000000000000000;
$scores=array(array());

for ($i=0;$i<18;$i++){
    $runningtotal=$values[$i][1]+$values[$i+1][1]+$values[$i+2][1];
    if ($highest<$runningtotal){$highest=$runningtotal;}
    if ($lowest>$runningtotal){$lowest=$runningtotal;}
    $scores[$i][1]=$runningtotal;
    $scores[$i][2]=$values[$i][0];
    $scores[$i][3]=$values[$i+1][0];
    $scores[$i][4]=$values[$i+2][0];
}

rsort($scores);

echo $highest."<br>".$lowest."<br><br>";

for ($i=0;$i<18;$i++){
    echo $scores[$i][1].": ";
    echo $scores[$i][2].",";
    echo $scores[$i][3].",";
    echo $scores[$i][4]."<br>";
}

?>
```